# PowerShell get applied windows updates HTML report

Tags: html, windows, powershell, report, updates

I have a PowerShell script that get's applied windows updates from 2003 servers and outputs the result to a .HTML report. What I like help on is how can I get each hotfix to list on a separate line instead of word-wrapped as in the below example?
[image]

Below  is the script

```
$servers = Get-Content 'c:\temp\servers.txt'

$total = $null
$html = @'
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
<title> Server Updates Report</title>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
td {
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 13px;
border-top: 1px solid #999999;
border-right: 1px solid #999999;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
border-left: 1px solid #999999;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
body {
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 10px;

table {
border: thin solid #000000;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width='100%'>
<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'><strong><font color="#003399" size="4"  face="tahoma">Server Patch Report </font></strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width='100%'><tbody>
<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<td width='20%' height='15' align='center'> <strong> <font color="#003399" size="2" face="tahoma" >Server Name</font></strong></td>
<td width='80%' height='15' align='center'> <strong> <font color="#003399" size="2" face="tahoma" >Patching Information</font></strong></td>
</tr>" 
</table>
<table width='100%'><tbody>
'@

foreach($server in $servers){
    $date = Get-Date '24/10/2013'
    $Updates = gwmi win32_ntlogevent -filter "logfile='system' and sourcename='ntservicepack'" -ComputerName $server | Where {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeWritten) -gt $date} 

    $newobj = new-object psobject
    $newobj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Server" -value $server 
    $newobj | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "Updates" -value $Updates.Message 
    $htmlserver = $newobj.Server
    $htmlupdates = $newobj.Updates

$current = " <tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<td width='20%' align='center'>$htmlserver</td>
<td width='80%' align='left'>$htmlupdates</td>
</tr> 
"     
$total += $current 
} 

$HTMLEnd = @"
</div>
</body>
</html>
"@

$MainHtml= $html + $total + $HTMLEnd
$MainHtml  | Out-File "c:\temp\Report.html" -Append
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a foreach-loop that goes through every update-event and removed the `newobj` code which seemed redundant. Does this work?

```
$servers = Get-Content 'c:\temp\servers.txt'

$total = $null
$html = @'
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
<title> Server Updates Report</title>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
td {
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 13px;
border-top: 1px solid #999999;
border-right: 1px solid #999999;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
border-left: 1px solid #999999;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
body {
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 10px;

table {
border: thin solid #000000;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width='100%'>
<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'><strong><font color="#003399" size="4"  face="tahoma">Server Patch Report </font></strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width='100%'><tbody>
<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<td width='20%' height='15' align='center'> <strong> <font color="#003399" size="2" face="tahoma" >Server Name</font></strong></td>
<td width='80%' height='15' align='center'> <strong> <font color="#003399" size="2" face="tahoma" >Patching Information</font></strong></td>
</tr>" 
</table>
<table width='100%'><tbody>
'@

foreach($server in $servers){
    $date = Get-Date '24/10/2013'
    gwmi win32_ntlogevent -filter "logfile='system' and sourcename='ntservicepack'" -ComputerName $server | Where {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeWritten) -gt $date} | ForEach-Object {

$current = " <tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
<td width='20%' align='center'>$server</td>
<td width='80%' align='left'>$($_.Message)</td>
</tr> 
"     
$total += $current 
} 
}
$HTMLEnd = @"
</div>
</body>
</html>
"@

$MainHtml= $html + $total + $HTMLEnd
$MainHtml  | Out-File "c:\temp\Report.html" -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet using the `-Fragment` and `-As LIST` parameters.

If the messages are in an array, it will convert it to t HTML you want

Comment: Thanks but this is an example of one thing I need to change and not the full script. The format needs to be as my example.